# Large Excel Data to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I am importing a large set of Excel data (about 150k rows and 115 columns) into SQL Server.

```
using IExcelDataReader 

Dim stream As FileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

' Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)

' Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
Dim excelReader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)

result.Tables
Dim result As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = True
Dim result As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()

'  Do a Bulk copy Here

excelReader.Close()
```

After waiting 2-3 minutes, I got a `System.OutOfMemoryException`

Is there a way to get rid of this exception and import the data faster?

I tried the `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider but it is not working on iis .

Comment: Do you really have to do that C#? I had the same issue and ended up using SQL.

Comment: Use the SQL Server Import Wizard. In the FROM data source section, choose Excel.

Comment: Your code looks like you just copied every example snippet from [Excel Data Reader - Read Excel files in .NET](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) and as such it would not compile.  Show the real code you are using.

Comment: I  added datatable=dataset.tables(0)  and then sql bulk copy code
(Column mapping then write to server) ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the excelReader.Read() method to iterate through each row, instead of returning the entire spreadsheet in a single call, which is what excelReader.AsDataSet() is doing (which is then causing you to run out of memory).

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for details on how to use a reader (although in that example it's a SqlDataReader, the logic should be the same).

The documentation for the ExcelDataReader [here](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) (scroll down) has a vague example which matches the SqlDataReader docs.